# Asking about deleted partition at boot

Tags: partitioning, wubi, windows-8

I have Ubuntu installed through Wubi. I also had another partition on my computer to try out the dev preview of Windows 8 aptly named Windows_8. After I was done playing, I deleted the Windows 8 partition and added the extra space back to my Win7/Wubi partition. Now every time I boot into Ubuntu, it tells me that it can't mount the partition and asks me if I want to recover or skip it. Is there a way to get Ubuntu to forget about this partition so I can skip this extra step in my boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find the corresponding line in your

```
/etc/fstab
```

file and comment it out. However, be very careful when editing this file as you can easily break the boot process of your system with a corrupted fstab.